# Can I used DAX to determine the difference between two fields within a given time period

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset that shows the total hours for every work item, with one row for each time the work item is updated (this is max 1 per day). Here is some sample data:

| WorkItem | CompletedWork | ChangedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12392 | 4 | 01/04/23 |
| 12392 | 4.5 | 03/04/23 |
| 12394 | 1 | 02/04/23 |
| 12394 | 4 | 07/04/23 |
| 12530 | 6 | 06/05/23 |

I need a DAX expression showing the work item hours for each time period, with the intention of using this in a line chart with weekly increments on the x axis showing work that has been completed in that time period.

I have tried writing this myself and cannot seem to get it working correctly. This is my current attempt and I feel I am close - any help would be appreciated

```
    CompletedWorkDifference = 
SUMX (
    VALUES ( Task_Revisions[WorkItemId] ),
    VAR CurrentRowWorkItemId = Task_Revisions[WorkItemId]
    VAR CurrentRowChangedDate = Task_Revisions[ChangedDate]
    VAR PreviousCompletedWork =
        CALCULATE (
            LASTNONBLANK ( Task_Revisions[CompletedWork], 1 ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( Task_Revisions ),
                Task_Revisions[WorkItemId] = CurrentRowWorkItemId
                    && Task_Revisions[ChangedDate] < CurrentRowChangedDate
            )
        )
    VAR CurrentCompletedWork = Task_Revisions[CompletedWork]
    RETURN
        IF ( PreviousCompletedWork <> BLANK (), CurrentCompletedWork - PreviousCompletedWork, BLANK () )
)
```

Comment: Please paste your expected output table

Comment: Do you have a separate Calendar table with all the time periods in it? (Year, Quarter, Month, Week etc).
If you do, this should be trivial. you can either use drilldown through a date hierarchy or you can use parameters to choose which level you want to summarize to.

Comment: @Pieter yes I have a calendar table with all of the above. This is falling over as the completed work is a total rather than a work in specific period. Meaning I would need to determine the first entry of the period, and the last entry and determine the difference for each work item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the following DAX, and joining to a date table that I had setup for the tasks

```
task_hours_by_time_period = 
SUMX(
    VALUES(task_revisions[WorkItemID]),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(task_revisions[CompletedWork]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(task_revisions[ChangedDateSK], 'Task_Calendar'[DateSK]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Task_Calendar'),
            'Task_Calendar'[Date] >= MIN('Task_Calendar'[Date]) &&
            'Task_Calendar'[Date] <= MAX('Task_Calendar'[Date])
        )
    ) - CALCULATE(
        SUM(task_revisions[CompletedWork]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(task_revisions[ChangedDateSK], 'Task_Calendar'[DateSK]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Task_Calendar'),
            'Task_Calendar'[Date] < MIN('Task_Calendar'[Date])
        )
    )
)
```